# CALayer not showing iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, calayer

In a contact form for my app the text input fields have a white line across the bottom of the box.

```
let border = CALayer()
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textInput.frame.height, width: textInput.frame.width, height: 3)
border.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
border.borderWidth = 3
textInput.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

The desired border shows up fine on iOS10 but when testing on iOS8 it doesn't show.

**Is there some niche to iOS 8 that I am unaware of?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Y point is height of the textinput make it 0 or something less than height

```
let border = CALayer()

border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textInput.frame.height - 3, width: textInput.frame.width, height: 3)

border.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

border.borderWidth = 3

textInput.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks Raj.